# Is there way to reverse the last half of the elements from the bottom of the stack (using recursion)?

Tags: java

The code which helps reverse the entire stack is however not able to get it to reverse half the elements -

```
static void reverseSecondHalf(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    // Write your code here
    
    if(stack.size() > 0)
    {
    
        int x = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();

        reverseSecondHalf(stack);
        insert_at_bottom(x,stack);}
    System.out.print(stack);
}
static void insert_at_bottom(int x, Stack<Integer> stack) {

    if(stack.isEmpty()) {
        stack.push(x);
    }
    else {
        int y = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        insert_at_bottom(x,stack);
        stack.push(y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant. And why do you want to use recursion? I would use 3 stacks: empty A into B to count, then half of B to C, then half to A, then C to A

Answer (score 1):

*this should be the shortest recursive solution*

```
public static void reverseLastHalf(int half, Stack<Integer> stack) {
  int tos = stack.pop();
  if(stack.size() > 0)
    reverseLastHalf(half, stack);
  if(stack.size() < half)
    insert_at_bottom(tos, stack);
  else
    stack.add(tos);
}
```

call it like this

```
reverseLastHalf(stack.size() / 2, stack);
```

*(Typically, stack-oriented languages like 7th have a function of rolling an element up from the bottom of the stack. The opposite way is unusual.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in Java-

```
    static void reverseSecondHalf(Stack<Integer> stack, int n) {
        // Write your code here
        if (stack.size()>(n/2+1) ){
            int top= stack.pop();
            reverseSecondHalf(stack,n);
            stack.add(n/2+1,top);
        }


    }
```

call in main like:

```
reverseSecondHalf(stack, stack.size());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static void reverseSecondHalf(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> result = new Stack<>();
    int size = stack.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i < size / 2)
            temp.push(stack.pop());
        else
            result.push(stack.get(size-(i+1)));
    }
    while (!temp.isEmpty())
        result.push(temp.pop());
    for(int i=0; i<size/2;i++) {
        stack.push(result.pop());
    }
    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation

Comment: @devseekinghelp has asked it to solve using recursion